# Fatal error: Out of memory - optimize php script

Tags: php, mysql

I have an sql database of 4 million records and I have build a php script to convert sql to json but failing to run the script even if I set memory_limit 4gb / 8gb (total RAM I have) is not enough. How can I alter my script in order to overcome this issue. I am using XAMPP:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '20000M');
//open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","newskill") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `ip_city_country_location`";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
$fp = fopen('empdata.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
fclose($fp);
```

TRIED ALSO WITH CSV on reading the file, but it's very slow

```
$file = fopen("iplocation.csv","r");
$i = 1;
while(! feof($file)) {
    if ($i <= 1000000) {
        $arr[] = fgetcsv($file);
    } else {
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Why are you using json, CSV would be a better choice as json requires holding the entire dataset in memory.

Comment: Ultimately you have to change your strategy to serial processing. So instead of loading everything into memory in parallel and even doubling it by conversions you only fetch a single row, write it into the output file and free the memory again. That way your script can scale and process arbitrary sized files.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix That is not true. Nothing speaks against writing JSON in exactly the same way as you would with a CSV format. The json format is no secret, it is easy to craft.

Comment: @arkascha - while it is possible to write json line by line, depending on the data and escaping needs it may be problematic.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Again there is not difference to CSV.

Comment: is the db properly indexed? if selecting all columns isn't necessary and you don't have hundreds of them, choose only the ones you "need".

Comment: When you fetch large data i recomend to use the columns you need and avoiding SELECT * .

Comment: Except that CSV is built to be written line by line, and you can use the built in functions to do it.  Unless you mean write one line of JSON then another, I was more meaning writing one big JSON object for the whole dataset.

Comment: Also, a `WHERE` clause with a LIMIT and possibly pagination could also help. That, or get more RAM ;-)

Comment: You can also look at UN-buffered queries, not sure how this applies to mysqli, I used PDO for the past 3 or 4 years exclusively.

Comment: Yes using LIMIT and OFFSET for paging .. clear memory usage on every page referer http://www.srcnix.com/tips/php/7-tips-to-prevent-php-running-out-of-memory/

Comment: Oh boy... It will be a long night.

Comment: I'm also of the mind that CSV would be a superior format for this. For one, MySQL can dump to it directly using [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html), it's very fast, and reading CSV files line by line is not really a problem for most systems. Even if you do overcome your JSON output problem now you have a multi-GB JSON document that's basically useless, nothing can read it without taking a huge memory hit.

Comment: Tried with csv and it's working much harder, it manages to output the content but in about 2 hours, updated my questions, the dbs has about 4 million rows.